# Create video player into UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit

I've UICollectionView and each cell has video when user click on that video it should start playing. This is what I tried :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
...
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        cell.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.videoUrl]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.playerItem];
            cell.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.player];
            cell.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

            cell.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
            cell.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 230);
            [cell.videoView.layer addSublayer:cell.playerLayer];

        });
    });
...
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    PostCollectionViewCell *cell = (PostCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

...
   [cell.player play];


}
```

So the problem is when I on video nothing happened it's not played and the `videoView` stay white. So did I missed something here ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Did you find a solution? @joey